# Hard Drive recognises everything as executable

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have an external Hard Drive that I use for storage data. In order to be able to execute file in this Hard Drive, I modified the /etc/fstab adding the following code:

LABEL=Data /media/Data  ntfs  default  0  0

In this way the Hard Drive is mounted with execute permissions, but now, if I check the files inside the Hard Drive with 'ls', all the files and folders are highlighted in green color (everything is potentially executable) and if I try to change the permissions using 'chmod' (eg. chmod 600 "file") nothing happens.

I would like to set the permissions of the files as in my /home folder. How can I do that?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Why did you use ntfs? Did this drive come from a windows machine?  I had the same problem with files I brought in from windows - all were executable.  But I was able to chmod them.

Comment: No, I just need a file system format that work well with ubuntu and windows and I think that ntfs is one of these.  Do you think that this problem could be solved with using ext4 format?